How to Visualize or Export Cloudflare WAF Rules?
I'm looking for a way to graphically visualize Cloudflare WAF (Web Application Firewall) rules. Does anyone know if there's a tool or method to achieve this? Alternatively, is there a way to export these rules to another tool for a comprehensive review?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.
